# transforming width of a polygon in SVG only hopefully

Tags: svg

Using basically SVG( except for PHP loops for positioning) only I would like to create a polygon shaped similar to >XX> where each X is simply top and bottom lines basically an arrow, which I have done.I duplicate this polygon offset by its width plus a few pixels along x.

Now I want to do a graduated fill of a different color on each polygon and it is offset by a about .1 secs

I do this with rectangles by simply printing them all out in first color then in the same xy coord locations draw the same rectangle in second color and animate its width from 0 to the normal width
the result is a graduated fill that moves along the x axis.

This can almost be achieved by redrawing each one uniquely in the different color but it would be very blocky I want each polygon to gradually fill from left to right
 I have looked at grouping, animate with the fill attribute and animateTransform with the scale attribute but am still learning the subtleties of each and may be missing something

the problem I see am seeing is the polygon has no width as designed and maybe I am just missing it.

I can use the rectangles for now but just wanted something flashier.

Any other avenues you could suggest I check out would be great

Here is code I have for the rectangles

```
<rect x='".($blk*$x)."' y='110' height='30' width='0' style='stroke:none; fill: #ffff00'>
                    <animate attributeName='width' attributeType='XML'
                        to='".($blk-3)."'
                        begin='".($x/15)."s'
                        dur='.5s'
                        fill='freeze'
                    />
</rect>
```

I use PHP for the blk size and the x translation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve a similar effect with animateTransform, applying a scale transform. animateTransform applies to all shapes including rect elements.

Don't forget that dur attributes must start with a leading 0 if they are less than 1 i.e. .5s is invalid and should be written as 0.5s

```html
<svg>
<rect x='100' y='20' height='30' width='0' style='fill: #ffff00'>
                    <animate attributeName='width' attributeType='XML'
                        to='100'
                        begin='1s'
                        dur='0.5s'
                        fill='freeze'
                    />
</rect>
<g transform='translate(100, 0)'> 
<polygon transform='scale(0, 1)'
         points='0, 110 40, 110, 40 140, 0 140'
         style='fill: #ffff00'>
                    <animateTransform attributeName='transform' 
                        type='scale'
                        to='2.5, 1'
                        begin='1s'
                        dur='0.5s'
                        fill='freeze'
                    />
</polygon>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I though I tried this but as you know the grouping of thing can have drastic differences but this works